# Formatting rows based on priority

Tags: c#, unit-testing, formatting

I'd like to improve the readability of the following code. The aim of this code is to apply formatting to row(s) in a `WinForms DataGridView` based on the Priority of an item, determined either by its `currentPriorityValue` or its `dueDate` property.

Because I've got tiger striped rows in the grid I used the modulo ternary to get the background to use by default. Then test for the High or Medium priority conditions and set the rowStyles conditionally.

I refactored *to* use a Tuple because it seemed to tidy the code up bit and let me assign values in my conditional logic, so there was just a single call to `FormatRowStyle` after the `if`/`else` `if`/`else`, but in the call to `FormatRowStyle` I think it no longer clearly expresses what it is doing. Specifically I don't like the `if`/`else` block and I don't like the call to `FormatRowStyle` with the nested Tuple properties showing as Item2.Item1...

Currently this logic is at the UI level. It is a presentational decision but I feel that it *should* be possible to have the logic handled elsewhere and that would make it easier to test.

```
private void ConditionallyFormatRowsForUrgency(int rowIndex, DateTime dueDate, string currentPriorityValue)
    {            
        var defaultBackColour = rowIndex % 2 == 0 ? VisualSettings.DefaultBackColour : VisualSettings.AlternateBackColour;
        var rowStyles = new Tuple<int, Tuple<Color, Color, Font>>(rowIndex, new Tuple<Color, Color, Font>(defaultBackColour, Color.Black, VisualSettings.RegularFont));

        if (ToDoUrgency(currentPriorityValue, "High", dueDate, 2))
            rowStyles = new Tuple<int, Tuple<Color, Color, Font>>(rowIndex, VisualSettings.HighPriorityStyle);
        else if (ToDoUrgency(currentPriorityValue, "Medium", dueDate, 7))
            rowStyles = new Tuple<int, Tuple<Color, Color, Font>>(rowIndex, VisualSettings.MediumPriorityStyle);

        FormatRowStyle(rowStyles.Item1, rowStyles.Item2.Item1, rowStyles.Item2.Item2, rowStyles.Item2.Item3);
    }

private static bool ToDoUrgency(string currentPriorityValue, string priorityLevel, DateTime dueDate, int daysGrace)
    {
        return currentPriorityValue == priorityLevel || dueDate <= DateTime.Now.AddDays(daysGrace);
    }


private void FormatRowStyle(int rowIndex, Color backColour, Color foreColour, Font font)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = backColour;
        dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = foreColour;
        dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.Font = font;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concentrating on the `ConditionallyFormatRowsForUrgency` method, I see three times `rowStyles = new Tuple<int, Tuple<Color, Color, Font>>(rowIndex, ...)` so that is something I would move to a common place. In fact, only its last argument -- lets call it `style` -- changes.

The initial value for `style` is actually the default for when the two `if`-statements don't fire. So I would put that initial value as an `else` to that `if`-statement.

Last but not least: `Tuple<Color, Color, Font>` accounts for most of the clutter. By specifying an alias (`using Style = Tuple<Color, Color, Font>` at the top) it conveys more meaning and makes it all more readable.

The end result would be like this:

```
using Style = Tuple<Color, Color, Font>;

private void ConditionallyFormatRowsForUrgency(int rowIndex, DateTime dueDate, string currentPriorityValue)
{
    var defaultBackColour = rowIndex % 2 == 0 ? VisualSettings.DefaultBackColour : VisualSettings.AlternateBackColour;

    Style style;
    if (ToDoUrgency(currentPriorityValue, "High", dueDate, 2))
        style = VisualSettings.HighPriorityStyle;
    else if (ToDoUrgency(currentPriorityValue, "Medium", dueDate, 7))
        style = VisualSettings.MediumPriorityStyle;
    else
        style = new Style(defaultBackColour, Color.Black, VisualSettings.RegularFont);

    var rowStyles = new Tuple<int, Style>(rowIndex, style);

    FormatRowStyle(rowStyles.Item1, rowStyles.Item2.Item1, rowStyles.Item2.Item2, rowStyles.Item2.Item3);
}
```

You could consider moving `defaultBackColor` into the `else` as that is the only place it is relevant.

---

In response to your latest edits: I think that your `ToDoUrgency` method is quite short, concise and easy to read. Maybe the length of the if-conditions make you think it is ugly, but there is not much you can do about it.

One important remark: in `ConditionallyFormatRowsForUrgency` the `style` variable should *never* be null, or you'll get a `NullReferenceException` later on, somewhere else. I therefore strongly recommend that you throw a `NotImplementedException` in the switch `default` case and remove the `= null` from the line `Tuple<Color, Color, Font> style = null`. Two reasons: if you ever add a new enum member to `Urgency` and you forget to add the appropriate `case` to the switch, you'll get an exception right there in your switch instead of in some other method (e.g. `FormatRowStyle`). If you then do add the case but forget to set the `style` variable to something valid, you'll get a compiler error stating that `style` might be used while it has not been assigned a value. This way you ensure that `style` is never null and that your switch covers all cases.

Further, on more personal preferences: I'd rename `ConditionallyFormatRowsForUrgency` to something like `FormatRowForUrgency`. The fact that it is conditional is an implementation detail: you might later on change how the formatting is done and this should not require you to change the name of the method. And it formats only one row, so use singular `Row` instead of `Rows`. You could also rename `ToDoUrgency` to just `ToUrgency` as that's what it does.

Lastly, your method `ConditionallyFormatRowsForUrgency` does not care about `DateTime dueDate` or `string currentPriorityValue`, yet is asks for them. Your method cares about `Urgency urgency` so that's what I would put in the parameters. This also makes your testing easier, as you can just put a single `Urgency` value in the method and see how it works. The conversion from `dueDate` and `currentPriorityValue` to an `Urgency` enumeration member may then be done somewhere else, and tested separately.

```
private void FormatRowForUrgency(int rowIndex, Urgency urgency)
{ ... }
```

---

In regards to the switch-statement: essentially there are four ways to accomplish what you want to do: as a switch-statement, as multiple if-statements, using inheritance, or as an index into a delegate array of functions. Multiple if-statements are probably uglier in this case than a switch-statement, and inheritance would require a complete rewrite of the Urgency enum to a class hierarchy. The index into a delegate array of functions would look like this:

```
private static readonly Func<int, Tuple<Color, Color, Font>>[] styleDelegates = new Func<int, Tuple<Color, Color, Font>>[]
{
    rowIndex => VisualSettings.HighPriorityStyle,     // assuming ToDo.Urgency.High = 0
    rowIndex => VisualSettings.MediumPriorityStyle,   // assuming ToDo.Urgency.Medium = 1
    rowIndex =>                                       // assuming ToDo.Urgency.Normal = 2
        {
            var defaultBackColour = rowIndex % 2 == 0 ? VisualSettings.DefaultBackColour : VisualSettings.AlternateBackColour;
            return new Tuple<Color, Color, Font>(defaultBackColour, Color.Black, VisualSettings.RegularFont);
        }
};

private void FormatRowForUrgency(int rowIndex, ToDo.Urgency urgencyLevel)
{
    var rowToStyle = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].DefaultCellStyle;

    Tuple<Color, Color, Font> style = styleDelegates[(int)urgencyLevel](rowIndex);

    FormatRowStyle(rowToStyle, style);
}
```

However, I would *not* recommend it. It is very likely that it severly reduces performance. There is just not much you can do about the switch statement and I would not mind seeing it there where it is now. But an alternative might be to move the switch statement altogether into another method, with the added benefit that it is possible to `return` early out of the switch.

```
private Tuple<Color, Color, Font> GetStyleByUrgency(int rowIndex, ToDo.Urgency urgencyLevel)
{
    switch (urgencyLevel)
    {
        case ToDo.Urgency.High: return VisualSettings.HighPriorityStyle;
        case ToDo.Urgency.Medium: return VisualSettings.MediumPriorityStyle;
        case ToDo.Urgency.Normal:
            var defaultBackColour = rowIndex % 2 == 0 ? VisualSettings.DefaultBackColour : VisualSettings.AlternateBackColour;
            return new Tuple<Color, Color, Font>(defaultBackColour, Color.Black, VisualSettings.RegularFont);
        default:
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}

private void FormatRowForUrgency(int rowIndex, ToDo.Urgency urgencyLevel)
{
    var rowToStyle = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].DefaultCellStyle;

    Tuple<Color, Color, Font> style = GetStyleByUrgency(rowIndex, urgencyLevel);

    FormatRowStyle(rowToStyle, style);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In response to your "*I still feel there's a better way of handling this than the switch"* sometimes when I see switches I think polymorphism and is there a way to handle this via OOP.  I typically don't do anything about it but at times it's hinting that I have a problem in my design and I should think a bit more deeper to put the necessary abstractions in place etc

In your case, although this might be needless complexity you could change your enum into a class hierachy of Urgencies.  Maybe something like.

```
   public abstract class Urgency
   {
       public Color ForeColor { get; private set; }
       public Font Font { get; private set; }
       private Color _defaultBackColor { get; }

       protected Urgency(Color color, VisualSettings.RegularFont font, VisualSettings.RegularFont defaultBackColor)
       {
           this.ForeColor = color;
           this.Font = font;
           this._defaultBackColor = defaultBackColor;
       }

       public virtual Color GetBackColor(int rowIndex)
       {
       return this.DefaultBackColor;
       }         

    }

    public class HighUrgency : Urgency
    {
       public HighUrgency(Tuple<Color, Color, Font> priority)
         : this(priority.item2, priority.item3, priority.item1)
      {

      }

      public HighUrgency(Color color, Font font)
        : base(color, font)
     {    
     }
  }

  public class NormalUrgency : Urgency
  {     
     public NormalUrgency(Color color, Font font)
       : base(color, font, VisualSettings.DefaultBackColour)
     {    
     }

  public override Color GetBackColor(int rowIndex)
  {         
     if(rowIndex % 2 == 0) 
     {
        return VisualSettings.AlternateBackColour;
     }
     else
     {
       return base.GetBackColor(rowIndex);
       }
  }
```

Then I would remove the switch and adjust your priority property to something like:

```
public virtual Urgency UrgencyLevel
{
    get
    {
        if (Priority.PriorityName == Urgency.High.ToString() || DueDate <= DateTime.Now.AddDays(2))
        {
            return new HighUrgency( VisualSettings.HighPriorityStyle);
        }
        else if (Priority.PriorityName == Urgency.Medium.ToString() || DueDate <= DateTime.Now.AddDays(7))
        {
           return new MediumUrgency( VisualSettings.MediumPriorityStyle);
        }
        else
        {
           // what about passing in VisualSettings.NormalPriorityStyle here??
           return new NormalUrgency(Color.Black, VisualSettings.RegularFont);
        }
   }
}
```

Then your method with the switch becomes something like:

```
private void FormatRowForUrgency(int rowIndex, ToDo.Urgency urgencyLevel)
{
    var rowToStyle = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].DefaultCellStyle;

    cellStyle.BackColor = urgency.GetBackColor(rowIndex);
    cellStyle.ForeColor = urgency.ForeColor;
    cellStyle.Font = urgency.Font;      
}
```

Adding a new Urgency then becomes a matter of adding a new class and adjusting the if else in the Urgency property.